# How to redirect page in itemAdded method in Custom List in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to redirect a page after of item added in method itemAdded in Custom List using Sharepoint:

```
  Public Class EventReceiver1
        Inherits SPItemEventReceiver

        Private current As HttpContext
        Shared obj As Object

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()

            If current Is Nothing Then
                current = HttpContext.Current
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub ItemAdded(properties As SPItemEventProperties)
            current = DirectCast(obj, HttpContext)
            MyBase.ItemAdded(properties)

            SPUtility.Redirect(properties.WebUrl & "/Paginas/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=" & properties.ListItemId, SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, current)


        End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub ItemAdding(properties As Microsoft.SharePoint.SPItemEventProperties)
      obj = current
    End Sub
End Class
```

Trying using `SPUtility.Redirect` but not works, works only in ItemAdding method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemAdded is asynchronous and occurs [after an item has been added](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded.aspx) to the library, i.e., you've already been returned to the library. So, I doubt you'll get a redirect to work from it. This is untested, but you could always set a hidden variable with the URL to which you want to redirect and use window.location on the client to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I needed to do this recently and revisited the question. You can hack your way around not having httpcontext in itemadded: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepointdevelopment/thread/8b7a652c-c027-419e-acff-c6ce56198108, http://www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2008/03/27/redirecting-from-newformaspx-to-dispformaspx-after-creating-a-new-item/